# How to make damage client sided in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm converting a simple platformer game into a multiplayer game(my first ever attempt at a multiplayer game), and i have these objects that if the player touches them, the player gets damaged. I'm having slight problems with server registering damage that shouldn't be, so to avoid all future problems i wanted to make damage client-sided.
I want to make it so all damage is client sided and the clients health gets sent to the server.

Edit: Made question less confusing.

```cs
public class EnemyTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerStats player;
    private CharacterController2D controller;

    public int Damage;
    public float horizontal;
    public float vertical;

    private void Start()
    {

    }

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.tag == "Player" && collider.GetComponent<PlayerStats>().DamageTimer <= 0 && collider.GetComponent<PlayerStats>().isDashing == false)
        {
            player = collider.GetComponent<PlayerStats>();
            controller = player.GetComponent<CharacterController2D>();

            player.TakeDamage(Damage);

            if (this.transform.position.x - player.transform.position.x > 0)
            {
                controller.KnockBackRight(horizontal);
            }
            else
            {
                controller.KnockBackLeft(horizontal);
            }

            controller.KnockBackDown(vertical);
        }

    }
}
```

```cs
public class PlayerStats : NetworkBehaviour {

    [SyncVar] public int Health;

    public GameObject BloodEffect;
    public Transform HealthBar;

    public float DefDamageTimer;
    public float DamageTimer;

    public bool isDashing;
    public int facingDirection;

    private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
    private CharacterController2D controller;
    public AnimationPlayer anim;

    private void Awake()
    {
        m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        HealthBar.localScale = new Vector3(Health / 10f, 1f);
        if (DamageTimer > 0)
        {
            DamageTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        CmdSendDashing(isDashing);
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int Damage)
    {
        Health -= Damage;
        Instantiate(BloodEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        anim.Damaged();
        Debug.Log("Player Has Taken " + Damage + " Damage");
        DamageTimer = DefDamageTimer;
        if (Health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        CmdSendHealth(Health);
    }


    void CmdSendHealth(int health)
    {
        Health = health;
    }

    void CmdSendDashing(bool isdashing)
    {
        isDashing = isdashing;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the collision (where damage only occurs on the server-side) registered on the client-side?

Comment: No, the client doesn't take damage on the clients side, but does on the servers side. Health gets lowered client-side, but I assume it's because it is a syncvar.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. The client always lies.

Comment: This game is meant for 2(or more) lan players, so the client being able to lie isn't a problem.

Comment: Yes, I am not talking of damage. I mean if the collision at least is being registered at the client-side? You may need to verify if the problem is with the actual collision or the registration of the damage. That's actually two separate things.

Comment: Well the collision happens, but the player has imunity at that time so they don't get damaged client-side,but sometimes do server-side. Idk if that helps.

Comment: As of how I read your question you want that damage to be applied on the client side. If so, why is the player imune? Is that a feature or your way to describe the actual problem?

Comment: Sorry if my question was confusing, the problem is that the client should be imune and not taking damage, which works fine on the client-side, but on server side the player sometimes gets damaged, which then lowers the health for the player eventually killing him.
My idea was to apply all damage client-side only and then send the players health to the server.

Comment: Usually the health (and damage) is being managed on the server side to prevent client-side tampering. That's what  Draco18s meant but you decide on that! Would you mind update your question and sum up: `What is happening`, `what you expect` and `how you tried` more detailed? So one (including me) may be able to help you as I still have trouble fully understanding your problem to the edge. Why is it impossible to make the player imune serverside too? (When) should the player recieve damage at all?

Comment: There's also a [GameDevelopment SE-Community](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/?tags=unity) where your question may recieve more attention!

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, and thanks for suggesting I visit GameDev community, I'll keep that in mind for the future. I solved my problem by having health in a separate script and completely disabling the damage script, only enabling it for each client. Just to clarify, what i wanted was to have the damage client-side only, I shouldn't have mentioned the reason, because that just made things more confusing, sorry.

Comment: Do not cross post to GameDev, request migration if you decide that your question is a better fit over there (note: "better" in this context means "is a game design question" not "I have a problem with my code (and my code is a game).")